# Can't change Firefox menu background color using userChrome.css on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, firefox

I can't change Firefox's menu background color using **userChrome.css** on **Windows 7**.

```
menubar, menubutton, menulist, menu, menuitem {
  color: red !important;
  background-color: orange !important;
}
```

This seems to work as the menubar changes to red and orange. But the background-color on the actual drop down menu stays the same (that Windows 7 menu look), although the text color does change to red.

Any ideas??

Comment: I guess you need to add the **menupopup** selector to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the built in settings editor for firefox and changing it manually.

First open a new tab (Firefox)

type in

```
about:config
```

press [Enter]

click the "I'll be careful, I promise" button.

type in

```
background
```

Now find the option that says

```
browser.display.background_color
```

Double click this option and change the default value

```
#FFFFFF
```

to whatever you want. (This code is in hex, so find the desired hex value and change it)

Everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for an answer, try this:

```
menubar, menupopup > * {
  color: red !important;
  background-color: orange !important;
}
```

Tested on Firefox 28.